'CPUDispatcher' object is not subscriptable error
I am trying to process a very large csv file. The csv file (companies.csv) contains a list of companies with a column of postal codes and some other columns. I have postalcode.csv file containing official postal prefixes in the UK, such as AB, B, E, EC, etc...  The aim is to filter out rows whose postal code don't start with the provided postal code prefixes.
For your convenience you may use this data
df = pd.DataFrame({'postal':['AB12', 'AL34', 'BA56', 'B78', '224876']})
prefixes = pd.Series(['AB', 'AL', 'B'， 'BA', ])

I am trying to run the following code with numba.jit on cuda engine
df = df[df['postal'].apply(lambda x: any(x.startswith(pc) for pc in prefixes))]

ChatGPT translated the code into this:
import numpy as np
from numba import njit

# Convert PostalCode to a set for faster membership check
postal_codes_set = set(PostalCode)

@njit
def starts_with_any(postal_code, postal_codes_set):
    for pc in postal_codes_set:
        if postal_code.startswith(pc):
            return True
    return False

@njit
def filter_postal_codes(postal_codes, postal_codes_set):
    filtered_indices = []
    for i in range(len(postal_codes)):
        if starts_with_any(postal_codes[i], postal_codes_set):
            filtered_indices.append(i)
    return filtered_indices

I have tried passing postal_codes as numpy.array or simple array. Numba just complains about the object and won't run it for me.
errors are:

argument 0: Cannot determine Numba type of <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
argument 1: Cannot determine Numba type of <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>



TypeError: 'CPUDispatcher' object is not subscriptable


TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
non-precise type array(pyobject, 1d, C)
During: typing of argument at /tmp/ipykernel_39251/917616573.py (10)
File "../../../../../../tmp/ipykernel_39251/917616573.py", line 10:

TypingError: Failed in cuda mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
non-precise type array(pyobject, 1d, C)
During: typing of argument at /tmp/ipykernel_39251/3483106034.py (1)
File "../../../../../../tmp/ipykernel_39251/3483106034.py", line 1:
I just can't get it work for me. What have I done wrong?

numba won't help you here (you're processing strings) How large is your df and prefixes ?

i am having 8gb data. it hasn't finished processing after 1 hour

How many rows has df and how many rows has prefixes?

the df has >6M rows. prefix is 11,226

I'm assuming the prefix must by followed by digit? Otherwise B and BA in prefixes could be reduced to only B?

yes, i have over-simplified the situation. it could be 5 alphanum characters

i am very shocked by learning numba won't help me. what can cuda do? i bought my GPU just trying to get some data work done quickly. so far, i haven't utilized my GPU. very depressed

There are many miss-conceptions here. First of all, by default, Numba code runs on CPU though there is a part of Numba which support Nvidia GPU (thanks to CUDA). Moreover, GPUs are really not made for such computation. There is a trend these days considering GPUs as accelerator that can automagically make all code much faster but this is completely wrong. GPUs are made to speed-up SIMT-friendly massively-parallel computationally-intensive operations. Additionally, end-user GPUs are designed to operate efficiently 32-bit (possibly 16-bit too) but not much other types.

Here, you compute short variable-sized dynamic unicode string objects which is a nightmare for GPUs (not SIMT-friendly). Moreover, the computation is not really intensive (rather memory-bound if one use an efficient native algorithm). Not to mention, data need to be sent to the GPU and retrieved back which is known to be slow (slower than the host RAM). It would be OK to use GPUs if significantly-longer fixed-size native ASCII/ANSI strings was computed instead and already stored on the GPU (no data moved between the host and the device).

In fact, the last point is so critical that GPUs can only be slower than a good CPU computation since moving data on GPU should always be slower than computing it directly in RAM (since it should be a memory-bound operation). Also note that the fact you use string object prevent the computation to be done in parallel due to the CPython GIL (Global Interpreter Lock). Python is generally clearly not great if you want fast codes.

Oh and, last but not least, Numba cannot make code using dynamic object faster. Numba is fast mainly because it operate on native types and also because all types are known at compile type. It first need to convert objects to native type which is pretty expensive here with many short strings (actually more than not converting strings). Not to mention Numba is clearly not optimized for (unicode) string computation yet (because it focus on numerical codes as pointed out by Andrej). And please read the Numba doc since the first page explain why you get the errors you see.

Based on your comment that prefix must be followed by digit I'd chose different strategy:

extract only first non-digit characters from  postal column
use Series.isin to create mask
filter the dataframe with this mask

cleaned_postals = df["postal"].str.extract(r"^(\D+)")[0]
mask = cleaned_postals.isin(prefixes)

print(df[mask])

Prints:
  postal
0   AB12
1   AL34
2   BA56
3    B78


in conclusion, there is no way to utilize my costly nvidia GPU?

You're processing strings, and GPU/Numpy/Numba/... are best suited to work with numbers. I'm not seeing easy way how you can utilize GPU here.

To OP: none of the information or methods depicted in the question have anything to do with a GPU.  njit and the like do not make use of a GPU, as you have depicted their usage.  Any answer to the question you have actually posed in the title would have nothing to do with any GPU method.  There is nothing at all in your question that suggests any interest in GPU, other than the cuda tag.   if you are serious about using a GPU for this kind of work, you would want to investigate RAPIDS.

While the provided has the benefit to be short/concise/simple, regular expressions are known to be generally rather slow (at least an order of magnitude slower than a manual parsing code).
